# Celery to process task and modify the model fields

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg, celery

I would like to convert video into mp4 using `ffmpeg` and `celery` for the asynchronous task. When user uploads a video, it will be for the `original_video` and save it. After that I want celery to convert it into a different version for the `mp4_720` field. However I am confused on how to apply that logic using celery.

app.models.py:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    original_video = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    mp4_720 = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
    converted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

app.views.py:

```
def upload_video(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = VideoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            video = form.save(commit=False)
            video.save()

            // Celery to convert the video
            convert_video.delay(video)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = VideoForm()
    return render(request, 'upload_video.html', {
        'form':form
    })
```

app.tasks.py:

```
@app.task
def convert_video(video):

    // Convert the original video into required format and save it in the mp4_720 field using the following command:
    //subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i (path of the original_video) (video for mp4_720)')

    // Change the converted boolean field to True

    // Save
```

Basically my question is how to save the converted video in mp4_720. Your help and guidance will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

** update **

What I want that method to do is first convert the video.original_video and then save the converted video in the video.mp4_720 field. If all has been done correctly, change the video.converted to True. How do I define the method to do so?

Comment: are you asking what the correct `ffmpeg` command line paramaters are?

Comment: @scytale I know the commands to execute ffmpeg. I don't know how to get the original video -> convert it -> and save it in mp4_720. Will you help me please.

Comment: can you please explain exactly what is missing or broken in the code you have posted?

Comment: @scytale I am confused in the convert_video() method. What I want that method to do is first convert the `video.original_video` and then save the converted video in the `video.mp4_720` field. If all has been done correctly, change the `video.converted` to True. How do I define the method to do so?

Comment: please update your question with the clarification you just gave in your comment

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably don't want to pass the `video` object to the celery - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079176/should-django-model-object-instances-be-passed-to-celery) question for details.

So you want to call it like this:

```
        convert_video.delay(video.id)
```

and then

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  # assuming you have set up logging elsewhere

@app.task
def convert_video(video_id):
    video = Video.objects.get(video_id)

    cmd = ['ffmpeg',  '-i', video.original_video.path, video.mp4_720.path]
    log.info('running %s', ' '.join(cmd))
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    proc.subprocess.wait()

    if p.returncode != 0:
        log.error('command failed with ret val %s', p.returncode)
        log.info(p.stderr)
        log.info(p.stdout)
    else:
        video.converted = True
        video.save()
        log.info('video converted ok')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check and get back soon.

Comment: Scytale, sorry I was really busy. How do you suppose I give the file name to the mp4_720, because it needs the filename for this function `get_upload_file_name()`?

Comment: no - the function is responsible for _creating_ the file name - see the [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to](docs)