# Django - Delay in creating database entry

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Django app where I create a db entry in the view. I then want to perform background processing on the new entry. Instead of sending the created object to the task, I send the object's id then the background task can fetch the db object as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079176/should-django-model-object-instances-be-passed-to-celery). Below is my code:

```
# In tasks.py
@shared_task
def my_task(model_id):
    my_model = MyModel.objects.get(pk=model_id)
    # Do stuff with my_model

# In views.py:
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        instance = MyModel.objects.create(**kwargs)
        tasks.my_task.delay(instance.id)
        ....
```

However, when I try to get the object in the background task, I get *matching query does not exist* error. If I add `sleep(1)` before getting the object, it works as excepted. I do not understand why I'm getting this error, since the object should be in the DB? Does anybody know how to solve this? I don't really want to add a sleep command everywhere.

I'm using Postgres as my DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
from django.db import transaction
with transaction.atomic():
    instance = MyModel.objects.create(**kwargs)
tasks.my_task.delay(instance.id)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Been struggling with this for hours!

Comment: I actually had to use transaction.non_atomic_requests since atomic requests were on already

Comment: @itzMEonTV can you please explain why it works?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/transactions/

> Performing actions after commit Sometimes you need to perform an
> action related to the current database transaction, but only if the
> transaction successfully commits. Examples might include a Celery
> task, an email notification, or a cache invalidation.
>
> Django provides the `on_commit()` function to register callback
> functions that should be executed after a transaction is successfully
> committed:
>
> `on_commit(func, using=None)`