# Object of type JpegImageFile is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, celery

I'm trying to use celery in my web app, but I don't know exactly how. I take out the image update in task, and he complains about the serializer constantly

tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
@shared_task
def update_image(image, width, heigth):
    output_size = (width, heigth)
    image.thumbnail(output_size)
    image.save()
```

models.py:

```
def save(self):
    img = Image.open(self.image.path)
    task = update_image.delay(img, self.width, self.heigth)
```

views.py:

```
 def put(self, request, pk):
        saved_content = get_object_or_404(Content.objects.all(), pk=pk)
        data = request.data.get('content')
        serializer = ContentSerializer(
            instance=saved_content, data=data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            content_saved = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "success": "Picture '{}' updated successfully".format(content_saved.id)
        })
```

Error:

```
Object of type JpegImageFile is not JSON serializable

Request Method: PUT
```

Comment: You can pass the Image object that way, pass the path of the image and open it inside of the task.

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079176/should-django-model-object-instances-be-passed-to-celery) in addition to @DavitTovmasyan's comment. Either pass the image path or re-fetch the object in your task by passing in the object's ID and do all object-related processing in your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the Image object that way, pass the path of the image and open it inside of the task.

```
task = update_image.delay(self.image.path, self.width, self.heigth)
```

task:

```
def update_image(path, width, height):
    image = Image.open(path)
    ...
```

Comment: great, you help me a lot.

Comment: But image don't change at admin panel, do you know why?

Comment: i understood reason of the problem: when i redefined the save method, I lost the ability to add elements via the admin panel. How to fix it?